# Is there a Ruby equivalent of using matplotlib and basemap in Python?

Tags: python, ruby, maps, equivalent

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/basemap/doc/html/users/installing.html

Is there an equivalent means for drawing on maps with Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't bridge your Ruby app to the Python lib?
See [How to Install MatPlotLib for Ruby](http://griff.sourceforge.net/matplotlib-ruby.html)

Comment: Thanks, can't even remember asking this, but I'll try it out.